# How can I make a weak reference to a parent object when using properties?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am not sure about it. Would I do that this way?

```
@property(nonatomic) MyParentObject *parentObject;
```

Note that I just left out the retain Keyword. Or would I have to write the Setter by myself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `retain`, you can use the `assign` attribute (which is actually the default). `assign` will prevent your generated setter from retaining or releasing `parentObject`. For example:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) MyParentObject *parentObject;
```

For a list of all attributes that can be used by Objective-C properties, take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW2).